# How to generate errors in every 24 hrs in new txt file using php?

Tags: php, error-log

I want to save errors of each date in txt file using PHP.. and I also want to name those  txt file by its date  .. eg ERROR-LOG
19-08-2022 I want to save my website every day error log in txt file ..which SHALL BE GENERATED FOR EVERY 24 HRS

I KNOW HOW TO MAKE ERROR LOG but m getting stuck . because as per the requirement I want to make error log for each date which shall be
generated in txt file and shall be named as per the date . I am newbie into programmming so will highly appreciate your support ...

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");

ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('log_errors',1);
ini_set('error_log',dirname(__FILE__).'/p.txt');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

// my code for generating error log ..now all errors are getting displayed in p.txt . but  I do not want that I want errors to be
generated for each date ...IN Separate txt file

Comment: So generate a string to use as the filename dynamically, based on the current timestamp - either using `date`, or `DateTime::format`.

Comment: Protip: this is not something your application code should be worried about. Your OS likely comes with a log-rotate program which will specifically *rotate log files* (which is the term you're looking for), and rename old log files to whatever pattern you want…

Comment: @deceze I am not getting u

Comment:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_rotation